# How to get a Component Ref props with Typescript React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a forwardRef Child components with implementation like below:

```
interface RefProps {
  prop1: () => void;
  prop2: () => void;
}

interface Props {
  prop1: string
}

const Child = forwardRef<RefProps, Props>((props, ref) => {
  // implementation...
})
```

I want to get the Child's ref props in the Parent component without having to export the interfaces

```
type ChildProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Child>

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef<?>(null);

  // implementation...
 
  return (
    <Child ref={childRef} ... />
  )
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically set to "?" like with ChildProps type?

Expectation: Dynamically get children's ref props

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to infer the type of forwarded `ref` from the parent component. So that we don't need to import the `RefProps` from the `Child` component.

```
// child.tsx
import React from 'react';

interface RefProps {
    prop1: () => void;
    prop2: () => void;
}

interface Props {
    otherProp: string
}

const Child = React.forwardRef<RefProps, Props>((props, ref) => {
    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        prop1() { },
        prop2() { }
    }), [])

    return null;
})

// parent.tsx

type InferRef<T> =
    (T extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<infer Ref>
        ? (Ref extends React.RefAttributes<infer RefElement>
            ? RefElement
            : never
        )
        : never
    )

type Ref = InferRef<typeof Child>

const Parent = () => {
    const childRef = React.useRef<Ref>(null);

    return (
        <Child ref={childRef} otherProp='a' />
    )
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0lElMAFHMAZzgG8qcYXDDcAjAC44ACgCUcALwA+OADcIwACYVKI0dwBM0+UtUbtugL5Ua9RszSsuEXgKEiIMABaMXYaR4YKDoAcyobako0CFoguABhb2AAGy0lNnQYADpMaAB3FCgtZEwAHlL-HgAaOCrlGRkxVxq4IkwFFXc9EWQs7IBXHiQASXBGFBhgNSQACRRaLRSkGXba0y6ZQR79YWawcVN+OCtqj12DV0Mjk-OTuVqAbQBdOVsdtqQYAahaOFoBikUtY3lEYABPMCsEa0TCMUplAAqqkUdxkiLgSAAHgxFnw+hhsgAxApFErsACiWK8wDQCVwkFoSHoZTocKgbEwyju+gA-LJSpiccytPjiDlSgBBGDBYAAIwGDB4rNhjE5FOWIGZMG5Hwuwn5pQ1SC19B5+ukTJmUHNwlB+rglqQ1ruoKoEKhnIyMPZCI9SAgmESyTSuqoMTi8A4RW1GQ2qm2+gj8TQIfJQcUmUJQyQCNKDQBQLkujuRG+v1ktrgZSSqXS7UU-FTddKVjgXl8UH8inwKHwcAA9Lr9KCrEA)